# Get all dropdown and multi select attrinbutes in system configuration

Tags: attributes, configuration, magento2.2.6

I have to get all the attributes which have type dropdown or multiselect in system configuration.

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Test</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\AttSource</source_model>
</field>
```

AttSource.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class AttSource implements OptionSourceInterface {

    protected $_attributeFactory;

    public function __construct(

\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory
) {

    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
}

public function toOptionArray() {
    $arr = [];
    $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::KEY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID, 4);

    foreach ($attributeInfo as $attributes) {
        $attributeId = $attributes->getAttributeId();
        // You can get all fields of attribute here

        $arr[$attributes->getAttributeId()] = $attributes->getFrontendLabel();
    }
    return $arr;
}
}
```

But above code is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
class AttSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

 protected $config;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config
) 
{
    $this->config=$config;
}
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $attributes=$this->config->getAttributesUsedInProductListing();

    $attributesArray = array();
    $attributesArray = array(
        array(
        'label' => __('Please Select'),
        'value' => ''
    )

    );
    $input_type_arr = array('select', 'multiselect'); 
    foreach($attributes as  $attribute){
        if (in_array($attribute->getFrontendInput(), $input_type_arr)):
            $attributesArray[] = array('value' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'label' => $attribute->getFrontendLabel());
        endif;

    }
    return $attributesArray;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code it's working fine for me.

```
<field id="allowattributesinview" translate="label comment" type="multiselect" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Simple Product Attributes to show in product detail page</label>
                    <source_model><vendor>\<module>\Model\Resource\ViewPageAttributes</source_model>
                    <comment>Selected attribute will display in configure product detail page.</comment>
                </field>
```

for options is below :

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Model\Resource;

class ViewPageAttributes {

    protected $_attributeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory
    ){
        $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray(){

        $attributesArray = array();
        $attributes = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*');

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $attributesArray[] = array('value'=> $attribute->getAttributeCode(),'label'=> $attribute->getFrontendLabel());
        }
        return $attributesArray;
    }
}
```

Change code as per your need.

Still facing issue let me know.

Comment: How can I add filter to get attributes which are dropdown and multiselect which are used for products?

Comment: could you please explain more about your comment

Comment: I want to get attributes which are only for products or from all attribute sets only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all the product attributes.

```
class AttSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray(){

        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $attributesArray = array();
        $attributesArray = array(
            array(
            'label' => __('None'),
            'value' => ''
            )
        );

        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $attribute) {
            $attributesArray[] = array('value'=> $attribute->getAttributeCode(),'label'=> $attribute->getFrontendLabel());
        }
        return $attributesArray;
    }

}
```